# Unable to Build Spring RestService Tutorial in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

I am attempting to work through the Spring Framework Restful Web Service creation tutorial(https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch) using Gradle and IntelliJ. I have followed everything to the letter but being fairly new to Spring, IntelliJ, and Java in general I'm unsure how to go about further debugging my issue.

When I attempt to build my project I receive a few errors stating "Java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist." I'm guessing I'm missing a library reference but am unsure how to check and include it.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework:spring-web:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'hello_springtest'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
        containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
        containers     'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

Just thought I'd add some additional information. I'm still seeing the errors and am unsure why but my project does report that the build was successful. When I attempt to make the project however that's when I receive the annotation does not exist error.

Comment: You've also followed the IDE steps for IntelliJ and Gradle https://spring.io/guides/gs/intellij-idea/ ?

Comment: @judoole So that looks like a walkthrough for importing a tutorial from Spring into IntelliJ. I was attempting to walk through and build it from scratch myself so none of that seems to really apply.

Comment: The walkthrough in the link is for this exact tutorial ref https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#use-sts The reason I asked is that the error looks like an error where IntelliJ has not imported the project correctly from build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You have some dependency in your builds script, which seems to me redundant and causes Gradle to look up for additional dependencies.

Just remove this dependency from your buildscript dependencies

```
classpath("org.springframework:spring-web:${springBootVersion}")
```

I see no reason to use it within your buildscript.

Comment: @Stansilav You're likely right, it was just something I tried in an attempt to find what I was missing. I've removed that line but unfortunately I'm still getting the same build error when I run my Project make.

Comment: That's odd, since `spring-boot-starter-web` depends on `spring-web` where the package `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation` is specified. May be you have to update your project, because not all the dependenies are yet downloaded? or run it with `--refresh-dependencies` flag